# custom tokenizer without using built-in token filters

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

How to create a custom tokenizer without using default built-in token filters?. e.g: Text: "Samsung Galaxy S9"
I want to tokenize this text such that it should be indexed like this

`["samsung", "galaxy", "s9", "samsung galaxy s9", "samsung s9", "samsung galaxy" , "galaxy s9"]`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
PUT testindex
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "filter_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "max_shingle_size": 20,
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": "true"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer_shingle": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "filter_shingle"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_shingle",
          "search_analyzer": "standard", 
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST testindex/product/1
{
  "title": "Samsung Galaxy S9"
}

GET testindex/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "analyzer_shingle",
  "text": ["Samsung Galaxy S9"]
}
```

You can find more about the shingles [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)

The first example is great and it covers a lot. If you want to use the standard tokenizer and not the whitespace, then you'll have to take care of the stop words as the blog post describes. Both of the urls are official ES sources

Comment: But shingles are only used to combine adjacent terms but I want to indexed text's words permutation.

Comment: Also, the max diff between Max-Min is depreciated to max diff of 3.
`#! Deprecation: Deprecated big difference between maxShingleSize and minShingleSize in Shingle TokenFilter,expected difference must be less than or equal to: [3]`